# Sliding fading animation in flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, animation, flutter-animation, slide

I am trying to achieve the [following result](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GEp7OjJiNiI_M1OV1MTYYtIg95TPnUu_/view?usp=sharing) in one of my app in flutter.
But I cannot figure out how to animate the "SKYGOAL" text that comes fading and sliding.
I've animated the rest of the components using AnimatedContainer or AnimatedOpacity, but I've been stuck on this one. I am new to animations so I don't know much.
Any help would be useful.
Thank you!

My current related snippet is :

```
class SplashScreen1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreen1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SplashScreen1> createState() => _SplashScreen1State();
}

class _SplashScreen1State extends State<SplashScreen1> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  double _skygoalLogoOpacity = 0;
  double _syjOpacity = 0;
  double _skygoalTextWidth = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 0)).then((value) => setState(() {
      _skygoalLogoOpacity = 1;
      _syjOpacity = 1;
      _skygoalTextWidth = 2000;
    }));
    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 4800)).then((value) => Navigator.pushReplacement(context, AnimatedPageRoute(SplashScreen2())));
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Color(0xFF0E3C6E),
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: [
            SizedBox(height: 250,),
            Stack(
              children: [
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.white
                  ),
                  height: 185,
                  width: 185,
                ),
                AnimatedOpacity(
                  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
                  opacity: _skygoalLogoOpacity,
                  child: Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                    child: Image.asset("assets/images/skygoal-logo.png"),
                    // height: 135,
                    width: 164,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Stack(
              children: [
                AnimatedOpacity(
                  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
                  opacity: _syjOpacity,
                  child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40, top: 37),
                    height: 29,
                    width: 153,
                    child: Image.asset("assets/images/start-your-journey.png"),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5,left: 20),
                  child: Text(
                    "SKYGOAL",
                    style: GoogleFonts.poppins(
                      fontSize: 30,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                      color: Colors.white
                    ),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),

              ],
            ),
            Spacer(),
            Text(
              "By Skygoal",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                fontSize: 13
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
              ),
              height: 5,
              width: 134,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include your current snippet

Comment: Sure, wait a min, let me just edit it

Comment: @YeasinSheikh did it

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`animated_text_kit`](https://pub.dev/packages/animated_text_kit)'s [fade](https://pub.dev/packages/animated_text_kit#fade)   animation

Example and result from doc

```dart
return SizedBox(
  width: 250.0,
  child: DefaultTextStyle(
    style: const TextStyle(
      fontSize: 32.0,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    ),
    child: AnimatedTextKit(
      animatedTexts: [
        FadeAnimatedText('SKYGOAL'),
      ],
     
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: But this fades the text all at once, I want a sliding effect.I can do this easily using AnimatedOpacity also, but I don't want this.